# column value processing in pyspark

Tags: python, regex, pyspark

i have a pipelinedrdd as below. there are more than 4k column in each row but i am showing only few.

```
 raw_rdd
 ['2016-09-21T00:00:00-05:00 Chicago,"","",150.39999389648438cfm,false,false,0.30000001192092896inHO,68F,70.69999694824219F,.....']
```

here I am trying to apply certain transformation such as if the field value match the regex `"\d{4}[-]\d{2}[-]\d{2}"` for a date value `2016-09-21T00:00:00-05:00 Chicago` then it should return only `2016-09-21T00:00:00-05:00`. but it is returning the original value.

code

```
def is_date(inst):
    if re.search("\d{4}[-]\d{2}[-]\d{2}", inst):
        return True

def transform(line):
    for i in range(len(line)):
        if is_date(str(line[i])):
            if str(line[i]) != "":
              line[i] = line[i].split( )[0]
    return line

transformed_rdd = raw_rdd.map(transform)
```

can anyone help me out to figure out the issue as where i am going wrong.

Comment: You are not returning the match, you only return True if there is a match and print the whole `line`. Return the `group(0)` and print it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was considering the entire row as a column value. after I did a split(,) I got the correct o/p